# How can I parse Json which starts with "/" in android using volley?

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

I am parsing json data from URl but it starts with "/". 
I have a data class which is a POJO class in the app. 
Here is my json file.

```
/{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "text": "Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed. Non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae. Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. "
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "text": "Volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum."
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my android code.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                try {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    JSONObject data1 = response.getJSONObject("data");
                    data = gson.fromJson(data1.toString(), Data.class);

                }
                catch (JSONException e){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error : "+ e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                dataList.add(data);
                mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(dataList,layoutInflater, viewPager2);

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

I am getting an error "Expected literal value at character 0.

Comment: That's not JSON. If you know everything from character 1 to the end _is_ valid JSON, just take `.substring(1)` before parsing.

Comment: I am parsing this JSON file as a JsonObject. where should I put .substring(1) before parsing?

Comment: You can't. `JsonObjectRequest` assumes you're actually getting JSON. You have to make a `StringRequest`, get a String from the response, substring it, then parse it yourself. Pointing `JsonObjectRequest` on something like this is cruel, like giving a homeless person canned tuna and wondering why he's not eating. :P

Comment: You are right. Got it thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove the "/" from the response by doing:

```
String subString = (respnse.tostring).replace("/","");
JSONobject jsonObj = new JSONobject(subString);
Gson gson = new Gson();
JSONObject data1 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
data = gson.fromJson(data1.toString(), Data.class);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hope it will Help!

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to remove the first slash use this:

```
if (jsonString.substring(0, 1).equals("/") {
    jsonString = jsonString.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before parse the object just remove the "/" from json.

```
String jsonString = response.toString();
if (jsonString.contains("/"))
   jsonString.replace("/","");
```

after that parse

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 JSONObject data1 = jsonString.getJSONObject("data");
 data = gson.fromJson(data1.toString(), Data.class);
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: That would remove all slashes from the JSON. You'd only want to remove the leading one, outside the actual JSON.

Comment: @Ridcully yup, thanks for knowing me, i edit my post.