# How to remove back slash ("\"") in JsonArray using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to Update multiple JsonObject data on server using JsonArray.

OutPut:-

```
["{\"stock_name\":\"1\",\"no_of_share\":\"1\",\"tranz_dt\":\"1\",\"buy_price\":\"1\"}","{\"stock_name\":\"2\",\"no_of_share\":\"2\",\"tranz_dt\":\"2\",\"buy_price\":\"2\"}","{\"stock_name\":\"3\",\"no_of_share\":\"3\",\"tranz_dt\":\"3\",\"buy_price\":\"3\"}"]
```

Output Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ItemModelList.size(); i++) {
    requestJson1.put("stock_name", ItemModelList.get(i).getStock_name().toString());
    requestJson1.put("no_of_share", ItemModelList.get(i).getNo_of_share().toString());
    requestJson1.put("tranz_dt", ItemModelList.get(i).getTranz_dt().toString());
    requestJson1.put("buy_price", ItemModelList.get(i).getBuy_price().toString());
   jsonArray1.put(requestJson1.toString());
}
requestJson.put("stockrow", jsonArray1.toString().replaceAll("\"", ""));
```

I expected result add Multiple Object using JsonArray without backslash with string.

Answer (score 2):

No string replacements necessary.

Just replace

```
jsonArray1.put(requestJson1.toString());
```

by

```
jsonArray1.put(requestJson1)
```

You want an array of JSON objects, not of strings.

Comment: Thanks for Reply, I already use jsonArray1.put(requestJson1) jsonArray1 print the last JsonObject of data. but I need put all JsonObject to JsonArray.

Comment: Read my answer again. You currently do not put the JSON objects into the array but a string representation of them.

Comment: Actually, Sir your answer not satisfied for me. How to remove "\" in my jsonObject.

Comment: That's because your question is an instance of an X-Y problem. If you do it correctly, there is no need to modify the resulting string. See also https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-the-xy-problem-and-why-is-it-bad--cms-21023

Answer (score 0):

"result" is JSON format string (like your OutPut) which you get.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

For example to get stock_name:

```
String[] stock_name;
stock_name = new String[jsonArray.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     stock_name[i] = jsonData.getString("stock_name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "/" to ""

```
result = result.replaceAll("/","");
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

Now in jsoanArray  have without "/" data. For more have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57071090/5110595)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the various `toString()` calls that are dotted around, and create a new `JSONObject` to add to your array for each ItemModel (otherwise you'll just end up with one item in your array).

```
for (int i = 0; i < ItemModelList.size(); i++) {
    final ItemModel im = ItemModelList.get(i);
    final JSONObject o = new JsonObject();
    o.put("stock_name", im.getStock_name());
    o.put("no_of_share", im.getNo_of_share());
    o.put("tranz_dt", im.getTranz_dt());
    o.put("buy_price", im.getBuy_price());
    jonArray1.put(im);
}
requestJson.put("stockrow", jsonArray1);
```